# How to get the metrics collected on datadog monitor using Java code?

Tags: java, spring-boot, datadog

I need to monitor fifty application. As apart of which I need to perform healthcheck on datadog dashboard to all the application everyday. So, Is it possible to collect the metrics collected in datadog from Java code
..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use datadog service-check which is also can be sent by the StatsDClient, and then add it to your monitor/dashboard page.
https://docs.datadoghq.com/developers/service_checks/

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [Datadog's Java / JMX integration](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/java/?tab=host) to capture the health data that's exposed over JMX -- this can probably give you up/down health data, and can certainly give you a lot more granular health metrics too.